# How to open emacs inside zsh terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, zsh

First of all, I use OSX.

When I use default bash and type `emacs` in terminal, it will open emacs inside terminal.

But when I switch to zsh, this operation will call my emacs app.

I have tried use `emacs -nw`, but the terminal just flash and nothing else happen.

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Sounds like a path issue. What does `echo $PATH` output in both `bash` and `zsh`?

Comment: @chepner I have tried, `echo $PATH` output is the same in both `bash` and `zsh`, I really don't know what's the matter.

Comment: What is the output for `type -a emacs` for both `bash` and `zsh`? It may be that for one or the other an alias or function is defined for running `emacs`.

Comment: Wow, it is the reason, now I fix this problem, thank you. @Adaephon